# How to add new field with various values to MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb

I have a large array of various numbers that is equal in length to the number of documents in my MongoDB collection. How do add this array as a new field ("X") to my MongoDB collection, e.g., doc1 has a new field "X" with value1, doc2 has a new field "X" with value 2 etc.

I'm not sure which operator to use, I know I can add update all documents in a collection with `db.collection.updateMany({}, {$set: {"X": value}})` but this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: have you considered using a bulk update?

Comment: Yes, doing `collection.bulk_write([UpdateOne({}, {"$set": {"X": i}}) for i in array])`  (pymongo) does not work. Only the first document is updated.

Comment: That's because `{}` will always match the first document.  You might try adding an additional field in the set, like a version that is constant for the entire run.  The for the match part, match only documents that do no have that field set.